# How to parametrize a triangle triangle

Tags: geometry

So lets say you have a triangle in 3d space with points $$A = (9,0,0)$$

$$B = (0,9,0)$$ $$C = (0,0,8)$$

how do you parameterize the triangle so that you have for example $r(u,v)$

i tried looking at other examples here they don't make sense.

Comment: Which other examples did you look at? I don't want to give an answer that you've already found unhelpful!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities.  For example

- you could specify a point on $AB$ as $uA+(1-u)B$ with $0 \le u \le 1$
- and so a point in $\triangle ABC$ as $uvA +(1-u)v B +(1-v)C$ with $0 \le u \le 1$ and with $0 \le v \le 1$

but you could alternatively choose a more symmetric $uA +v B +(1-u-v)C$ with $u \ge 0$ and $v \ge 0$ and $1-u-v>0$

Comment: You may want to check your first parametrization. That's not a triangle.

Comment: @jjagmath.  Thank you - better now?

Comment: Yes, that is the triangle $ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

Points inside a triangle are just various weighted averages of the vertices. So you're looking at something like $uA+vB+wC$ for $u, v,$ and $w$ being larger than 0 and adding up to 1.

In other words, you're looking at: $uA+vB+(1-u-v)C$ for $u$ and $v$ being larger than 0, and $1-u-v$ also being larger than 0 (i.e. $u + v \leq 1$)